# Cannot create AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory (Dependency Issue)

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-rest-api

I previously made a restful client application in Java to mass-manipulate tickets and expedite workflow, however, I want to create a more holistic application that utilizes the actual JIRA api instead of parsing JSON in my own solution.
I have a very simple code-block to create a client:

```
public class SimpleMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      JiraRestClient client = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
        .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI("https://jira.redacted.com"), "redacted", "redacted");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Attempting to create a simple AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory results in the following exception:

```
15:12:06.625 [main] DEBUG c.a.j.r.c.i.a.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory$MavenUtils - Could not find version for maven artifact com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-com.atlassian.jira.rest.client
15:12:06.633 [main] DEBUG c.a.j.r.c.i.a.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory$MavenUtils - Got the following exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory$MavenUtils.getVersion(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:158) ~[jira-rest-java-client-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory$RestClientApplicationProperties.getVersion(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:121) [jira-rest-java-client-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.getUserAgent(DefaultHttpClient.java:168) [atlassian-httpclient-apache-httpcomponents-0.13.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:139) [atlassian-httpclient-apache-httpcomponents-0.13.2.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53) [jira-rest-java-client-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35) [jira-rest-java-client-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42) [jira-rest-java-client-core-3.0.0.jar:na]
at jiratest.SimpleMain.main(SimpleMain.java:13) [classes/:na]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.nio.client.HttpAsyncClient.start()V
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:162)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53429', transport: 'socket'
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.createClient(AsynchronousHttpClientFactory.java:53)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:35)
at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
at jiratest.SimpleMain.main(SimpleMain.java:13)
```

From what I have been reading, this is a dependency issue because of differing libraries. Here is what I'm using:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <pojomatic.version>2.0.1</pojomatic.version>
    <jira-api.version>6.1.1</jira-api.version>
    <jira-rest-java-client-core.version>3.0.0</jira-rest-java-client-core.version>
    <httpcore.version>4.4.1</httpcore.version>
    <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira-rest-java-client-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcore.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcore.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcore.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pojomatic</groupId>
        <artifactId>pojomatic</artifactId>
        <version>${pojomatic.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Does anyone know what versions I should be using? Am I still missing dependencies? I've been reading through atlasian q/a's and various google documents and I think I'm close but I'm not sure what I'm still missing.

Thanks to all in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual issue lays in the fact that Spring's transitive dependencies override atlassian's transitive dependencies. The way to fix this is to wrangle the dependencies back to what the jrjc needs them to be, instead of the more up to date versions.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1-atlassian-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.0-beta3-atlassian-1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

NOTE: These versions will probably change in future releases, but they work for JRJC core version 3.0.0. You can find out by reading the output of `mvn dependency:tree`, it will say something like: `httpasyncclient:jar:4.0.2:compile - version managed from 4.0-beta3-atlassian-1` which lets you know that maven is using version 4.0.2 of `httpsyncclient`, so you need to override it back to `4.0-beta3-atlassian-1`.

Comment: In the `dependency:tree` I see exaclty these two dependencies and adding your suggested dependecyManagement section did not help to get rid of the NullPointerException :(

Comment: It's possible that you have another dependency that is conflicting with the jrjc core. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and see if you're seeing any `version managed from` messages on any others. Pull them down to the from version in the dependencyManagement section, and then rinse and repeat. Sometimes, if you have multiple dependencies, you actually get pulled up MULTIPLE times instead of just once for a given dependency so the only way to know is to manage/check multiple times.

Comment: @dokaspar It's more than likely too late for this, I just realized it was probably because you needed to clean your maven project of old dependencies. `mvn clean install -B -U` to remove and then gather the most up to date dependencies as defined by the pom file.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue, and solved it the following way:
I had both

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
  <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atlassian.httpclient</groupId>
  <artifactId>atlassian-httpclient-apache-httpcomponents</artifactId>
  <version>0.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in my pom.xml file. Turned out client-core already had httpcomponents inside, and they clashed. Removing second dependency fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the other solutions on the internet, modifying my log4j2 configuration worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="qed.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory$MavenUtils" level="OFF"/>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

The key part of the configuration is:

```
<Logger name="com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousHttpClientFactory$MavenUtils" level="OFF"/>
```

Obviously it doesn't fix the problem, but it does hide it.

As nasty as the NullPointerException seems to be, it has no effect on the creation of the ApacheAsyncHttpClient, see:

```
        try {
            resourceAsStream = MavenUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(String
                    .format("/META-INF/maven/%s/%s/pom.properties", groupId, artifactId));
            props.load(resourceAsStream);
            return props.getProperty("version", UNKNOWN_VERSION);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Could not find version for maven artifact {}:{}", groupId, artifactId);
            logger.debug("Got the following exception", e);
            return UNKNOWN_VERSION;
        } finally {
```

Comment: You have to look back at my stacktrace: `at jiratest.SimpleMain.main(SimpleMain.java:13)`, this was actually preventing my application from running. So, unfortunately, this was not the same thing you're seeing.